# Vue.js get selected option on @change

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a combobox and want to do something different based on the selected combobox. I use a separate `vue.html` and TypeScript file.
Here's my code:

```html
<select name="LeaveType" @change="onChange()" class="form-control">
  <option value="1">Annual Leave/ Off-Day</option>
  <option value="2">On Demand Leave</option>
</select>
```

Here's my TypeScript file:

```js
onChange(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

How do I get the selected option value in my TypeScript function?

Answer (score 318, accepted):

Use `v-model` to bind the value of selected option's value. [Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/13qpbzcn/3/).

```
<select name="LeaveType" @change="onChange($event)" class="form-control" v-model="key">
   <option value="1">Annual Leave/ Off-Day</option>
   <option value="2">On Demand Leave</option>
</select>
<script>
var vm = new Vue({
    data: {
        key: ""
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(event) {
            console.log(event.target.value)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

For more info [click here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select)

Comment: it's getting error "key is not defined".  do i have to define v-model first? if yes, how?

Comment: Yes, you can set any name to replace the key. But make sure that this is a property of data.

Comment: I still, dont get it.. i know i can rename it to any name, but i getting a warning "[Vue warn]: Property or method "selected" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property"

Comment: Maybe there is a typo in your script because there is no existance of word 'selected' in the script. Please check it and refer to the link in the answer. I add a demo example in it.

Comment: "selected" is my model name. if i rewrite your code, my warning will become "key" is not defined

Comment: "key" has been defined in the data. Can you copy your code to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or github?

Comment: The link you add didn't work. An error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` occurs. Pleay don't use es6.

Comment: it's solved. just initialize the value when it's declared. Thanks

Comment: since the tag says asp.net-mvc, remember that @ invokes razor syntax in a view, so imo its preferable to use v-on

Comment: It's also possible to use `this.key` instead of `event.target.value` inside `onChange` method.

Comment: Why use @change. This is what watch is made for. Here is the modified [example](https://jsfiddle.net/csp8wy6n/) of the example in the answer.

Answer (score 53):

**@** is a shortcut option for **v-on**. Use **@** only when you want to execute some Vue methods. As you are not executing Vue methods, instead you are calling javascript function, you need to use **onchange** attribute to call javascript function

```
<select name="LeaveType" onchange="onChange(this.value)" class="form-control">
 <option value="1">Annual Leave/ Off-Day</option>
 <option value="2">On Demand Leave</option>
</select>

function onChange(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

If you want to call Vue methods, do it like this-

```
<select name="LeaveType" @change="onChange($event)" class="form-control">
 <option value="1">Annual Leave/ Off-Day</option>
 <option value="2">On Demand Leave</option>
</select>

new Vue({
  ...
  ...
  methods:{
    onChange:function(event){
       console.log(event.target.value);
    }
  }
})
```

You can use **v-model** data attribute on the select element to bind the value.

```
<select v-model="selectedValue" name="LeaveType" onchange="onChange(this.value)" class="form-control">
 <option value="1">Annual Leave/ Off-Day</option>
 <option value="2">On Demand Leave</option>
</select>

new Vue({
    data:{
        selectedValue : 1, // First option will be selected by default
    },
    ...
    ...
    methods:{
        onChange:function(event){
            console.log(this.selectedValue);
        }
    }
})
```

Hope this Helps :-)

Comment: I get the following error when I execute second one in vuejs:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Comment: I haven't used "apply" anywhere in the Code. Could you please share the code in which you are getting the error?

Answer (score 35):

The changed value will be in `event.target.value`

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      message: "Vue"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      console.log(event.target.value);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select name="LeaveType" @change="onChange" class="form-control">
   <option value="1">Annual Leave/ Off-Day</option>
   <option value="2">On Demand Leave</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 23):

You can also use [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) for the rescue

```
<template>
    <select name="LeaveType" v-model="leaveType" @change="onChange()" class="form-control">
         <option value="1">Annual Leave/ Off-Day</option>
         <option value="2">On Demand Leave</option>
    </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            leaveType: '',
        }
    },

    methods: {
        onChange() {
            console.log('The new value is: ', this.leaveType)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: How do I append input text depends on the selected option?

Answer (score 6):

onChangeMethod --> method of your choice, it can be anything related to your program.

```
<template>
<select @change="onChangeMethod($event)">                                            
  <option value="test">Test</option>
  <option value="test2">Test2</option>
</select>
</template>

<script>
 data(){
   return{
    ...
     
   }
 },
 methods:{
     onChangeMethod(event)
     {
         console.log(event.target.value);
     }
 },
 created(){
   ...
 }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your **@change="onChange()"** an use watchers.
Vue computes and watches, it´s designed for that.
In case you only need the value and not other complex Event atributes.

Something like:

```
  ...
  watch: {
    leaveType () {
      this.whateverMethod(this.leaveType)
    }
  },
  methods: {
     onChange() {
         console.log('The new value is: ', this.leaveType)
     }
  }
```

Comment: Please note that watchers are expensive. the above can also be achieved as a computed property, which is far more cheaper.