# How does one pass the selected value or index of a select in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

This appears simple and easy from the question, however Given:

```
<select id="lstMash" @change="onChange()"><option value="valid">Valid</option><option value="warning">Warning</option><option value="error">Error</option></select>
```

I need to get the value or index of the selected option. I am using Vue, VueRouter, and Vuex.Store. This being said, v-model, v-bind use data in app, which in my case does not exist (Use will only cause errors). How can i get the required data to pass with the event, or how in general if that's an incorrect method?

Thanks in advance! Ps. any additional info needed will be posted

EDITS:

App:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    components: { all, mash, boil, ferm }
});
```

Store:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        Mashing: [],
        Boiling: [],
        Fermenting: [],
        btnMashToggle: '^',
        btnBoilToggle: '^',
        btnFermToggle: '^',
        allShow: false,
        mashShow: false,
        boilShow: false,
        fermShow: false,
        mashGroup: true,
        boilGroup: true,
        fermGroup: true,
        channel: "",
        status: "",
        message: "",
        timestamp: ""
    },
    mutations: {
        // Adds new message
        newmessage: function(state, message) {
            switch (message.channel) {
                case "mashing":
                    store.state.Mashing.push(new Message(Message.id, message.channel, message.status, message.message, message.timestamp));
                    break;
                case "boiling":
                    store.state.Boiling.push(new Message(Message.id, message.channel, message.status, message.message, message.timestamp));
                    break;
                case "fermentation":
                    //store.increment(new Message(Message.id, message.channel, message.status, message.message, message.timestamp));
                    store.state.Fermenting.push(new Message(Message.id, message.channel, message.status, message.message, message.timestamp));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        },
        // Loads Stored Messages
        loadInit: function(msg) {
            for (m in msg) {
                switch (msg.channel) {
                    case "mashing":
                        store.state.Mashing.push(new Message(Message.id, m.channel, m.status, m.message, m.timestamp));
                        break;
                    case "boiling":
                        store.state.Boiling.push(new Message(Message.id, m.channel, m.status, m.message, m.timestamp));
                        break;
                    case "fermentation":
                        //store.increment(new Message(Message.id, message.channel, message.status, message.message, message.timestamp));
                        store.state.Fermenting.push(new Message(Message.id, m.channel, m.status, m.message, m.timestamp));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        },
        // Toggles Mashing Section on All Page
        toggleMash: state => {
            state.mashGroup = !state.mashGroup;
            state.btnMashToggle = state.mashGroup ? '^' : 'v';
        },
        // Toggles Boiling Section on All Page
        toggleBoil: state => {
            state.boilGroup = !state.boilGroup;
            state.btnBoilToggle = state.boilGroup ? '^' : 'v';
        },
        // Toggles Fermenting Section on All Page
        toggleFerm: state => {
            state.fermGroup = !state.fermGroup;
            state.btnFermToggle = state.fermGroup ? '^' : 'v';
        }
    }
});
```

All Template for component:

```
<All id="all" v-show="$store.state.allShow">
    <div>
        <h3>Dashboard</h3>
        <!-- Mashing Group -->
        <div id="mashGroup" class="groups">
            <div id="mashHead">
                <h3>Mashing Status</h3><select id="lstMash" @change="onChange()"><option value="valid">Valid</option><option value="warning">Warning</option><option value="error">Error</option></select><button id="btnMashToggle" @click="btnMashToggle_Click()">{{this.$store.state.btnMashToggle}}</button></div>
            <div id="allMash" v-show="$store.state.mashGroup">
                <table id="tblMash" prefix="tblMash">
                    <tr id="tblHead">
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                    </tr>
                    <transition-group name='mashMessage'>
                        <tr v-for="m in $store.state.Mashing" :key="m.id" mode="out-in">
                            <td v-if="m.status=='valid'" class="valid">{{m.status}}</td>
                            <td v-else-if="m.status=='warning'" class="warning">{{m.status}}</td>
                            <td v-else-if="m.status=='error'" class="error">{{m.status}}</td>
                            <td>{{m.message}}</td>
                            <td>{{m.timestamp}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </transition-group>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Boiling Group -->
        <div id="boilGroup" class="groups">
            <div id="boilHead">
                <h3>Boiling Status</h3><select id="lstBoil"></select><button id="btnBoilToggle" @click="btnBoilToggle_Click()">{{this.$store.state.btnBoilToggle}}</button></div>
            <div id="allBoil" v-show="$store.state.boilGroup">
                <table id="tblBoil" prefix="tblBoil">
                    <tr id="tblHead">
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                    </tr>
                    <transition-group name='boilMessage'>
                        <tr v-for="b in $store.state.Boiling" :key="b.id" mode="out-in">
                            <td v-if="b.status=='valid'" class="valid">{{b.status}}</td>
                            <td v-else-if="b.status=='warning'" class="warning">{{b.status}}</td>
                            <td v-else-if="b.status=='error'" class="error">{{b.status}}</td>
                            <td>{{b.message}}</td>
                            <td>{{b.timestamp}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </transition-group>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Fermenting Group -->
        <div id="fermGroup" class="groups">

            <div id="fermHead">
                <h3>Fermentation Status</h3><select id="lstFerm"></select><button id="btnFermToggle" @click="btnFermToggle_Click()">{{this.$store.state.btnFermToggle}}</button></div>
            <div id="allFerm" v-show="$store.state.fermGroup">
                <table id="tblFerm" prefix="tblFerm">
                    <tr id="tblHead">
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                    </tr>
                    <transition-group name='fermMessage'>
                        <tr v-for="f in $store.state.Fermenting" :key="f.id" mode="out-in">
                            <td v-if="f.status=='valid'" class="valid">{{f.status}}</td>
                            <td v-else-if="f.status=='warning'" class="warning">{{f.status}}</td>
                            <td v-else-if="f.status=='error'" class="error">{{f.status}}</td>
                            <td>{{f.message}}</td>
                            <td>{{f.timestamp}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </transition-group>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</All>
```

Comment: How do you mean v-model,v-bind will cause errors? This should be very easy with V-model <select v-model="selected">

Comment: See the app, the data part is a store. I'm not sure how those could be applied (Is it possible?)

Comment: @user10783878 please provide the data object and the store code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50982499/7639883

You will find 2 ways of doing this in the provided url: one with a simple JS function and a way of doing it with VueJs.

don't forget to change the onchange method with the parameter(if using JS) otherwise if using vue dont forget to change like `@change="onChange"`

Answer (score 2):

```
methods: {
  onChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately event is undefined

Comment: @change="onChange()" take out "()" @change="onChange"

Comment: Was almost perfect. Had to change to @change="this.onChange"
Thanks!

Comment: @user10783878 I don't want to be that guy, but just in case someone else comes across this, I don't want them to draw the wrong conclusion.
you certainly did not need to change it to @change="this.onChange" 
 There is no need to specify "this" inside your template (you can do it, but it is by no means necessary). 
Adam's reply to your "event is undefined" comment was correct. By including the empty parentheses, you were specifying that the the method call should have no arguments. And as a result, the event object that is attached to onchange events by default is lost.