# Using Vue how do you call a function when a user clicks on a bootstrap-selectpicker option

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have multiple selectpickers in a vue component when a user clicks on an option I want to call a function passing in an id

```
<tr v-for="(content) in searchResults" v-bind:key="content.id">
   <td>{{ content.title}}</td>
    <td>
        <select class="selectpicker">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select Option</option>
            <option value="Reject" @v-on:click="rejectArticle(content.id)">Reject</option>
            <option value="Preview" @v-on:click="previewArticle(content.id)">Preview</option>
            <option value="Approve" @v-on:click="approveArticle(content.id)">Approve</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

However this is wrong. What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: probably use onchange of select, similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982408/vue-js-get-selected-option-on-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use @change, as noted in the response, this is how that would look like
template: `@change="onChange($event, content.id)"`

in the handler, you can then access the value with `event.target.value`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { searchResults:[{id:1, title:'ABC'}, {id:2, title:'DEF'}] },
  methods: {
   onChange(event, id) {
      console.log(event.target.value, id)
      switch (event.target.value) {
        case rejectArticle:
          this.rejectArticle(id)
          break;

        case previewArticle:
          this.previewArticle(id)
          break;

        case approveArticle:
          this.approveArticle(id)
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <table>
  <tr v-for="(content) in searchResults" v-bind:key="content.id">
     <td>{{ content.title}}</td>
      <td>
          <select class="selectpicker" @change="onChange($event, content.id)">
              <option value="" selected disabled>Select Option</option>
              <option value="Reject">Reject</option>
              <option value="Preview">Preview</option>
              <option value="Approve">Approve</option>
          </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```