# vue.js loop option value in object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**i have the object like this**;

```
fluit:[
    {id:'001', name:"Apple"},
    {id:'002', name:"Banana"},
    {id:'003', name:"Mango"},
    {id:'004', name:"orange"},
    {id:'005', name:"papaya"},
  ]
```

**And code in vuejs like this**

```
<select >
  <option v-for="(item, index) in fluit" :key="index" :value="item.id" id="select"{{item.name</option>
</select>
```

**and what i get from this tag it's like this**

[image]

and what i want to ask is how can i get the value as the id of each option. like a when i select **Mango** and the value is **003**.
if you know how to solve this please help me.
thank you.

Comment: This could be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982408/vue-js-get-selected-option-on-change

Answer (score 1):

For Your Solution use this -

```
<template>
    <select name="itemType" v-model="itemType" @change="onChange()" class="form-control">
         <option value="001">Apple</option>
         <option value="002">Banana</option>
    </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            itemType: '',
        }
    },

    methods: {
        onChange() {
            console.log('The new value is: ', this.itemType)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

My advice use vuetify (v-select)component with vue for better performance.

```
<template>
     <v-select
        v-model="select"
        :items="fluit"
        item-text="id"
        item-value="name"
        label="Select"
        @input="doSomething"
        return-object/>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        select: { id:'005', name:"papaya" },
        items: [
           {id:'001', name:"Apple"},
           {id:'002', name:"Banana"},
           {id:'003', name:"Mango"},
           {id:'004', name:"orange"},
           {id:'005', name:"papaya"},
        ],
      }
method:{
      doSomething(){
       console.log(this.select)
      }
    }

    },
  }
</script>
```

I Hope it will help!

Answer (score 1):

add a v-model to your select and that is it:

```
<select v-model="selectedItem">
  <option v-for="(item, index) in fluit" :key="index" :value="item.id" id="select"> 
   {{item.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

now selectedItem will contain the value of the fruit, working example :
https://codesandbox.io/s/fruit-select-vs709

Comment: hi dear, thank you i have got it. you are so helpful