# How to detect event on Vue.js on select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I’m trying to identify an event by click, change or keydown
This is my code for listen event:

```html
<div class="form-group input-group mb-3">
  <select 
    title="" 
    @change="onChange(this.value)" 
    v-model="formData.region" 
    class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" 
    id="region" 
    style="width: 100%; height: 35px !important;" 
    data-select2-id="1" 
    tabindex="-1" 
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <option selected="selected" disabled>Выберите область</option>
    <option v-for="(region, $index) in regions" :key="$index" :value="region.id">{{region.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```js
onChange(){
  alert('yes');
},
```

this is my code of declared formData

```js
data() {
  return {
    formData: {
      region: '',
    }
  }
},
```

None of these methods worked out

Comment: How is formData declared? Are there any errors?

Comment: Does this answer your problem?
[Vue.js get selected option on @change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982408/vue-js-get-selected-option-on-change/50982531)

Comment: i sav this topic and try use some issues but this is no get result for me
Wthy not idk

Comment: fornData is declared in data(){return{}}. I dont have any error on click, change or something else

Comment: region data im get from axios request. Then im import to the component mapGetters this data and  with help v-for im displaying in select option tag this data. In the next step im need at event show another select option tag which is hidden

Comment: Change ``@change="onChange(this.value)" `` to ``@change="onChange" `` and ``v-model="formData.region" `` to ``v-model="formData[region]" ``, so you can use the model inside the function as follows: ``this.formData['region']``. You may have to change the code since I cannot debug it in this way.

Comment: Thanks for help and nice try but this is not working. Idk why