# 1 way binding fails after selecting option in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, bind, v-model

I'm trying to implement 1-way binding. What I want is that changing dropdown should affect the text in `<p>` and the  text. Change  tag should effect only text within `<p>`. But when I change the dropdown value, I lost the value within the `<p>` as well as within the  tags

```
<span class="wt-select">
    <select id="student_skill" v-model="selected">
        <option v-for="(stored_skill, index) in stored_skills" :key="index.id" :value="stored_skill.id">{{stored_skill}} hours</option>
    </select>
    <p>{{ selected }}</p>
    <input :value="selected" type="text" class="form-control" id="date_time">
</span>
```

How can I achieve this? I tried the following link, but still unable to achieve this one-way binding:

[Vue.js get selected option on @change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982408/vue-js-get-selected-option-on-change)

Comment: @change="pText=$event"

Comment: What's pText here?

Comment: have you checked the console tab for any errors ? and one more thing, index doesn't have an id property as it is a number not an object

Comment: Replace input and p text with new variable add change event to select - would be my guess solving your issue