# How to get ID from select box in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js

I'm trying to get  `idTipoExame` from this JSON:

```
{
  "idTipoExame": "11",
  "mnemonico": "AUR",
  "exame": "ACIDO URICO"
},
{
  "idTipoExame": "24",
  "mnemonico": "BTF",
  "exame": "BILIRRUBINA TOTAL E FRACOES"
},
```

I tried to use @change, but I get "exame" from target.value.
Here my Code Html and My function:

Javascript:

```
ExameEvent(event) {
console.log(event.target.value)
}
```

HTML:

```
 <select v-model="Exame" @change="ExameEvent($event)>
    <option v-for="item in JSON" :key="item.JSON">{{item.exame}}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js get selected option on @change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982408/vue-js-get-selected-option-on-change)

Answer (score 0):

You could add the value to the option tag and then get the value from the event.

```
<option v-for="item in JSON" :key="item.JSON" :data-id="item.idTipoExame">
```