# How can i open my modal only when i click on the "New" option?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Im trying to open my modal in VueJS only when i click on the "New" option, how can i do that?

```
      <select v-model="input.des"   @change="$refs.modalName.openModal()">              
           <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
           <option value="New">New</option>
          </select>



openModal() {

  this.show = true;
  document.querySelector("body").classList.add("overflow-hidden");
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected value of the selected option from `event.target`. You can find more on that in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982408/vue-js-get-selected-option-on-change).

Change your code to:

```
<select v-model="input.des" @change="$refs.modalName.openModal">              
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="New">New</option>
</select>

openModal(event) {
    if (event.target.value == "New") {
        this.show = true;
        document.querySelector("body").classList.add("overflow-hidden");
    }
},
```

Comment: I was using this and it works. However, I once new is selected - if we want to allow clicking on new again to open the modal (to edit some form), it will not open modal unless we change the select option to something else and come back to new. Is there a way to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for that would be to `watch` for option changes:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      input: {
        des: ''
      },

      show: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    openModal() {
      this.show = true;
      document.body.classList.add('overflow-hidden');
    }
  },

  watch: {
    'input.des'(val) {
      if (val === 'New') {
        //this.$refs.modalName.openModal();

        this.openModal();

        alert('Modal opened');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="input.des">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="New">New</option>
  </select>
</div>
```