# How to trigger on change event on multi select using Vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

this is my html multi select input:

```
<select id="invitees_list1" class="form-select" multiple name="multi">
    @foreach ($seatedTable->invitees as $invitee)
         <option>
            {{ $invitee['name'] }}
           </option>
       @endforeach

  </select>
```

and the vue js code:

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/admin/app-assets/js/scripts/vue2.min.js') }}"></script>
     <script>
         const app = new Vue({
             el: '#filtersContainer',
             data: {
                 invitees: [],
                 selectedInviteeIds: [],
                 inviteesList: [],
                 selectedTableInfo: null,
                 eventTables: [],
                 newTableName: "",
                 totalChairNumberEntered: 0,
                 confirmedInviteesRoute: "{{ route('invitee_tables.confirmed_invitees', $event) }}",
                 selectedInviteesRoute: "{{ route('invitee_tables.assignModalData', $event) }}",
                 assignTableRoute: "{{ route('invitee_tables.assign', $event) }}",
                 isDisabled: false
             },
             created() {
                 axios.get(this.confirmedInviteesRoute)
                     .then(({
                         data
                     }) => {
                         if (data?.status) {
                             this.invitees = data?.data || []
                         }
                     })
                     .catch((err) => console.log(err))
             },
             mounted() {
                 $("#name_filter").select2()
                 $('#side_filter').select2()
                 $('#caller_filter').select2()
                 $('#relation_filter').select2()
                 $('#invitees_list').select2()
                 $('#invitees_list1').select2()

                 $('#invitees_list1').show()

                 $("#invitees_list").show()

             },
```

I want to when ever the multi select changed ,i want to get the value of the multi select input and trigger an event.
I've tried javascript event but nothing happened .

Comment: I can't see any handler? Where is your @change?

Comment: I add @change also but nothing happened.

Comment: I think @change should work (on the select element) and the options should a have value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68071387/3791775

Answer (score 1):

To trigger an event whenever the multi-select input changes, you can use the @change directive in Vue.js.

```
<select id="invitees_list1" class="form-select" multiple name="multi" v-model="selectedInviteeIds" @change="handleMultiSelectChange">
    @foreach ($seatedTable->invitees as $invitee)
        <option :value="{{ $invitee['id'] }}">
            {{ $invitee['name'] }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Vue.js

```
const app = new Vue({

    // code

    methods: {
        handleMultiSelectChange() {
            // This method is called when the multi-select input changes
            console.log('Selected Invitee IDs:', this.selectedInviteeIds);

            // Add your custom logic or trigger an event here
            // For example, you can emit a custom event
            this.$emit('multiSelectChanged', this.selectedInviteeIds);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you , I will try it , one more question if I want to make the dropdown of multi select to be always open when user is selecting ,how to do it?

Comment: you can use the :open prop of the vue-multiselect component

Comment: I have tried the solution it worked but the style of the tag multi select in vue js is gone and return to default styleof html multi select